# Is there a proper greeting for the Three Weeks and Tisha B'av?

Tags: tisha-bav, speech-talking, nine-days, three-weeks

Is there a proper greeting for the Three Weeks and Tisha B'av? For some reason "goodday" or "shalom aleichem" don't seem like good greetings for a period of mourning.

Comment: You're not allowed to greet people on Tisha bav...

Comment: During the 3 weeks, you can greet people in the same "normal" way you would every other day of the year, e.g. "Hello", "Good morning", "Yo guy", etc. Tish'a B'av you shouldn't greet someone else in any way; not even a wave or acknowledgement. If someone else greets you, you respond in a curt and quiet voice so that they don't feel offended. But, otherwise, absolutely no greeting should be given to anyone.

Comment: There's someone I know who greets people with "Not hi" on Tisha B'Av. Not sure how halachically sound that is, but there you have it.

Comment: @DonielF Weird. That sounds like the same idea of counting people in the minyan by "Not one; not two.." You're still counting with a number, and there you're still greeting. In the answer, I'm a bit surprised that waving is acceptable. I guess one could state that's its a way to get attention and not necessarily a greeting.

Comment: As per [this discussion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84438/is-there-a-proper-greeting-for-the-three-weeks-and-tisha-bav/84461?noredirect=1#comment265290_84461), you might want to specify if you're looking for a source in halacha or if you're just looking for good suggestions (the latter probably being either too broad, opinion-based, or both).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on (O.C. [554:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.554.20?lang=bi&with=Halakhah&lang2=en)) אֵין שְׁאֵלַת שָׁלוֹם לַחֲבֵרוֹ בְּתִשְׁעָה בְּאָב, וְהֶדְיוֹטוֹת שֶׁאֵינָם יוֹדְעִים וְנוֹתְנִים שָׁלוֹם, מְשִׁיבִים לָהֶם בְּשָׂפָה רָפָה וּבְכֹבֶד רֹאשׁ,

Rav Ari Enkin concludes his [article](http://hirhurim.blogspot.com/2008/08/greeting-people-on-tisha-bav.html) saying,

> While it may just be that those who choose to be strict and not offer
>   any greeting whatsoever when in mourning or on Tisha B'av are
>   following a preferred course, it cannot be suggested that a simple
>   social acknowledgment is in violation of halacha. Those who feel that
>   it is rude or uncomfortable to pass others without an acknowledgement
>   of some sort should feel free to offer a somber "hello" without
>   reservation.[Be'er Moshe 4:106] Often merely saluting another person in a somewhat
>   formal manner and tone of voice ("Mr. Levine") accomplishes the same
>   thing as well.

Although Guidelines (Q:263) writes not to nod in greeting on Tisha B'Av, [this](http://agudathisrael.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Halachos-of-the-Three-Weeks.pdf) pamphlet put out by the Agudah (p26) writes

> Nodding and Waving are Permissible

Answer (score 1):

I always say "have an easy fast".

Comment: Welcome! When you get enough reputation, you'll be able to comment on anyone's post.

Comment: that was a answer, that's honestly that I would say tbh.

Comment: If you interpret the question as "what would you say on Tisha B'Av" then it would be closed as opinion-based. The intent seems to be looking for sources in Halacha as to what is appropriate and what is not, as the other answer does.

Comment: I like this answer. ;) Although the other answer is what I was looking for. +1 on this one, though.

Comment: @DonielF The OP said nothing about halakha. It asked what is proper, and this user answered what seems proper. You can critique the OP for being vague, but not this post for answering it.

Comment: @mevaqesh [Better?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84438/is-there-a-proper-greeting-for-the-three-weeks-and-tisha-bav/84461?noredirect=1#comment265306_84438)

Comment: @DonielF Except too late, as after answers are upvoted he cant change the question anyway.

Comment: Did any gedolim ever say "have an easy fast" (some one told me that it is not a Jewish thing to say)